# Translation Golf XXVII - I am the one who knocks

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

**Game over**
*A guy opens a new TG edition and gets an [111-char shot](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23424/13628) and you think that of [psosuna](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17803/psosuna)? No. He is the one who wins!*

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This edition's proposed text is one of the most famous monologues in recent television history: Walter White's ["I am the one who knocks"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMEq1mGpP5A&t=52s) from TV series *Breaking Bad*:

> Who are you talking to right now? Who is it you think you see? Do you know how much I make a year? I mean, even if I told you, you wouldn't believe it. Do you know what would happen if I suddenly decided to stop going into work? A business big enough that it could be listed on the NASDAQ goes belly up. Disappears! It ceases to exist without me. No, you clearly don't know who you're talking to, so let me clue you in. I am not in danger, Skyler. I am the danger! A guy opens his door and gets shot and you think that of me? No. I am the one who knocks!
>
> <sub>(416 characters)</sub>

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

As an example, non-golfed translation, I will use the official Spanish dubbing (even though it is actually shorter than the original):

> ¿Con quién estás hablando ahora? ¿A quién te crees que tienes delante? ¿Sabes cuánto gano al año? Si te lo dijera no te lo creerías. ¿Sabes lo que pasaría si decidiera dejar de ir a trabajar? Un negocio tan grande como para estar en el NASDAQ se hundiría. ¡Desaparecería! Dejaría de existir sin mí. No, está claro que no sabes quién soy. Te diré algo. Yo no estoy en peligro, Skyler. ¡Yo soy el peligro! Un tío abre la puerta y dispara, ¿crees que sería a mí? No. ¡Yo soy el tío que llama!
>  
>  <sub>(370 characters)</sub>

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: One of the best moments of one of the best tv series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### <s>167</s> <s>141</s> 111 caracteres

> No sabes de mí ni mi salario. Sin mí, un negocio mayor se hunde. ¿Yo, en peligro? Skyler, ¡yo lo soy! No abro la puerta y recibo balas, ¡soy quien llama!

Notas:

1. Gran parte de no creer es no saber.
2. Un negocio tamaño NASDAQ es enorme. Uso el término mayor para denotar de los más enormes.
3. Creo se puede simplificar aún más. Seguiré buscando. Trataré de no usar palabras antiguas, para no crear copias totales.

<s>***Edits previos:***</s>

> No creerías quien soy y cuanto gano. Sin mí, un negocio tamaño NASDAQ
>   se inunda. No estoy en peligro, Skyler, ¡yo lo soy! No soy a quien le
>   disparan al abrir la puerta, ¡soy quien llama!
>
> ¿Sabes quien soy y cuanto gano? No lo creerías. ¿Y si renunciara? Un
>   negocio tamaño NASDAQ al bote. ¡Fín! Acaba sin mí. Te diré: No
>   estoy en peligro, Skyler, ¡yo lo soy! No soy quien abre la puerta y es
>   disparado, ¡yo la llamo!

Comment: Opté por hacer ajustes que sean menos centricos en coloquialismos regionales para evitar confusiones.

Comment: Parece que has hecho un mezcla de las tres traducciones. Normalmente preferimos no usar las ideas de los otros, aún así buen trabajo!

Comment: @blonfu Admito haber usado ideas que se han visto. Pero, parte del juego es no reinventar la rueda, sino buscar de entre tantas soluciones la que resulta más corta. Por el camino que iba, no habría mucho más que reducir. Por igual, invito a que se use mi respuesta como base si se puede reducir más, no tengo ningún problema con tal cosa. :)

Comment: Esto se pone interesante. Siempre me sorprendo de cuánto se puede llegar a resumir un texto.

Answer (score 4):

#### <strike>208</strike> 132 caracteres

> ¿Sabes con quién [fablas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HR9V1Ah)? ¿Cuánto gano? Ni lo atisbas. Sin mí, un [afer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0wvHFOy) tamaño [IBEX 35](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBEX_35) sería [fumo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IbIVmGC). Una [seña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XbgS1p9): no corro peligro, Skyler, si uno abre su [uzo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bDvyQXy) y le [balean](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4t2Llvr), ¡yo hago [ta-ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YqvDmDI)!

Explicaciones:

- ...

Demasiadas explicaciones, ¡esto es la guerra!

Comment: Ya que estás con palabrejas antiguas ¿por qué no usar *qui* y *cuan* en lugra de *quien* y *cuánto*?

Comment: @blonfu veo que "qui" es "quien" pero no "quién". No sé si se puede usar en este caso. Y "cuan" solo viene en el DLE como apócope de "cuanto" en su acepción 9. Pero por supuesto seguiré investigando palabras antiguas... :-)

Comment: Es verdad, igual no se pueden usar en este caso, eso pasa por no investigar un poco antes de hablar

Comment: @blonfu en realidad sí podía usarla, al final en "yo soy qui llama", pero luego he encontrado otra forma aún más corta. :-D

Comment: @walen va, pongo "IBEX 35" que son las mismas letras y así nadie se queja. :-D

Comment: Compañía holandesa de las Indias Orientales (Verenigde Oostindische Compagnie, o "VOC") Mira, puedes poner VOC.

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>336 206</s> 201 caracteres

> No creerías quién soy y cuánto gano. Sin mi, un negocio que podría
> estar en NASDAQ al garete. No sabes con quién hablas, Skyler. No estoy
> en peligro ¡Yo soy el peligro! ¿Crees que soy el tipo que abre su
> puerta y recibe un balazo? No. ¡Soy el que llama a la puerta!